# Pass a parameter to dataProvide when using the @Factory TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, testng

There is an exception Using TestNG's @Factory and @dataProvider annotations it is not possible to pass the calling test name, this needed when building a generic test as a framework to provide different data each time(from Excel). Using Method getName() at the Dataprovider cause run time Exception. The getName() function is working when using @dataprovider only. However combined with @Factory the exception occurs. Is there a ways to solve or bypass this issue?

```
package Tests;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public abstract class GenericFactory11 {
    protected  List<String> data;


    public GenericFactory11(List<String> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "getDataForInstances")
    public static Object[][] getDataForInstances(ITestContext context,Method m){
        System.out.println(context.getName());
        System.out.println(m.getName()); // THIS Line Causes the exception

        return new Object[][]{
                {Collections.singletonList("Java")},
                {Arrays.asList("TestNG", "JUnit")},
                {Arrays.asList("Maven", "Gradle", "Ant")}
        };
    }
}
```

```
package Tests;

import static org.testng.Assert.assertNotEquals;

import java.util.List;

import org.testng.annotations.Factory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Sanity11 extends GenericFactory11 {

      @Factory (dataProvider = "getDataForInstances")
      public Sanity11(List<String> data) {
            super(data);
        }

    @Test
      public void Sanity(){
        String text = this.data.get(this.data.size()-1);
         System.out.println("Printing Parameters when running test method [" + text + "]");
          assertNotEquals(text,"");
      }
}
```

Running the code the following error is received:

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodNoCheckedException(MethodInvocationHelper.java:49)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing a `NullPointerException` because your data provider states it would be accepting a `java.lang.reflect.Method` object, but in this case, the calling method is a `java.lang.reflect.Constructor` and not a `Method` object.

You should be replacing `java.lang.reflect.Method` with `org.testng.ITestNGMethod`.

Here's how your modified data provider looks like:

```java
@DataProvider(name = "getDataForInstances")
public static Object[][] getDataForInstances(ITestContext context, ITestNGMethod method) {
    System.out.println("test name = " + context.getName());
    System.out.println("Method name = " + method.getConstructorOrMethod().getName() + "()\n");

    return new Object[][] {
      {Collections.singletonList("Java")},
      {Arrays.asList("TestNG", "JUnit")},
      {Arrays.asList("Maven", "Gradle", "Ant")}
    };
}
```

Comment: WOW This works thanks! However, now I'm experiencing another issue with this architecture. After test is completed I cannot see the parameters sent to the Method. If I am using dataProvider for the method itself without any @Factory the Results page do show what were the parameters this method was called by. Any suggestions on how showing the parameters? Thanks!

Comment: If it was not clear which results page I was referring see the following screenshot. http://prntscr.com/ohyej5

Comment: @SeleniumStar - Depending on the IDE that you are using, I would suggest that you file an issue on their respective Issue Tracker page.

Comment: Thank you Krishnan! It seems it is not Eclipse issue rather more TestNG issue, because testng-results.xml do not display any parameters too. I just looked at the following issue: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1041 and seems as the same issue i am experiencing. Was this issue fixed?

Comment: I opened the following issue regarding the test result. Thanks! https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/2117